# Django makemigrations error :The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pycharm

MacOS 10.9.2, python 2.7.10

I install PyCharm version3.4 and select to create a django project for the first time, and the application begins to download django version 1.9;

But when I type “makemigrations” in “run manage.py task”, it shows error:

bash -cl "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py makemigrations /Users/apple/PycharmProjects/DjangoProj"
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DIRS.
No changes detected

Process finished with exit code 0

And when I type”migrate”, it shows:

bash -cl "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py migrate /Users/apple/PycharmProjects/DjangoProj"
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DIRS.
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
  Apply all migrations: admin, contactor, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Process finished with exit code 0

settings.py is:(already updated)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'contactor',//created by myself
)
```

I know it is just a warning, but it still exists an error when I type:

```
from contactor.models import Person
```

in python console...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/apple/PycharmProjects/DjangoProj/contactor/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Person(models.Model):
  File "/Users/apple/PycharmProjects/DjangoProj/contactor/models.py", line 5, in Person
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1081, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

This means I have to update my init.py also?

Comment: Your error message does not match your question in any way at all. What error are you actually getting?

Comment: I have already updated it ~

Answer (score 1):

> WARNINGS: ?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DIRS. No changes detected

This is just a warning. You don't need to downgrade to Django 1.8. To stop the warnings, you need to update your settings. There is a [guide to upgrading your template settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/upgrading/#upgrading-templates-to-django-1-8) in the Django docs.

To import the models, the settings need to be configured correctly.The easiest way to do this is to use the `shell` command from `manage.py`.

```
./manage.py shell
```

If you are trying to use the shell in Pycharm, you will need to make sure that the settings are configured correctly. I can't offer any advice how to do this.

Comment: I have already updated my settings but when I type  "from contactor.models import Person" later, it shows errors like this:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/apple/PycharmProjects/DjangoProj/contactor/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Person(models.Model):
  File "/Users/apple/PycharmProjects/DjangoProj/contactor/models.py", line 5, in Person
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

Comment: It looks like you haven't included the full traceback there. Please edit the question and add the traceback there, it's very hard to read in the comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot~ I'll try it~

Answer (score -1):

@knRao

1. for the error message

> The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django

change your template directory name to TEMPLATES

2. For migrations error make sure you have not edited init.py file and correct your models for any errors.